# How does __destruct work with objects in $_SESSION

Tags: php, oop, session

If an object in PHP is stored in the session, `$_SESSION`, when will it's `__destruct` method be called?  I haven't been able to find any clear answer in the manual. It does say that `__destruct` will be automatically called at the end of script execution, so my expectation is that it will be called regardless of it's existence in `$_SESSION`.

Does this then mean that potentially `__destruct` will be called on every request for an object in the session?

**Added**:
Will the object be serialized before or after `__destruct`?  Will modifications in `__destruct` be reflected in the next request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't actually store an object in session, you store it serialized as a string.  You can then override the magic `__sleep` and `__wakeup` methods on the object. `__sleep` gets called when an object is serialized and `__wakeup` will be called when you attempt to unserialize an object.

For more info, see:

[Manual Documentation for __sleep and __wakeup](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php)

[Manual Documentation for Storing Serialized Objects in Session](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.serialization.php)

Comment: One more clarification if you know, is the object serialized before or after `__destruct` is called?

Comment: The object will not be serialized and stored in session automatically.  It will be serialized when you call the serialize method, as in: `$_SESSION['index'] = serialize($obj);`  You should probably do this before the `__destruct` method is called.

Comment: From what I could gather, the objects are serialized before `__destruct` is called.  So using `__sleep` and `__wakeup` are the key.  As a note, in the doc it looks like `__wakeup` doesn't have to return a list of properties like `__sleep` does. It's important in my case because I'm using a parent class to wrap some basic functionality, and I'd have no good way of knowing which properties would be needed for each sub class.

Comment: `$_SESSION['index'] = $obj;` should call serialize directly. **https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=36696** This bug report helped clarify a few things, check the notes.

Comment: Correct.  Since a 'serialized object' is nothing more than a string, __sleep must tell PHP what properties it wants to PHP to add to the string.  All __wakeup does is take the string, scan it for the object properties, and restores the object with all of the properties set correctly.  The return value of calling `unserialize` is the object itself.

Answer (score 0):

`__construct` and `__destruct` are called every time a script is ran with an instance of that object.  If you put an object in a session, that object does not hold the same value across page views, it is simply an object.  I wrote a quick example to demonstrate this:

```
class MyClass{
    var $myVar=1;
    function __construct(){
        $this->myVar++;
    }
    function __destruct(){
        echo "destruct";
    }
}
session_start();
$_SESSION['object']=new MyClass;
echo $_SESSION['object']->myVar;
```

The output of this is:

> destruct2destruct

This part throws me for a little loop, and I hope someone out there can correct me if I am wrong.  `__destruct()` is being called twice because the object is created and then destroyed when putting it into the session.  Echoing out the `$_SESSION['object']->myVar` reinitiates the object and then is subsequently destroyed.

If you modify your code and take out `$_SESSION['object']=new MyClass;` and re-run the script, it will produce:

> 2destruct

Again, the object is destroyed as the object is called, and the function is finished executing.  Basically if you store your object in a session, expect that it will be destroyed every time you access the object.